# Extract the list of unique numbers out of a string of numbers

Tags: python, string, list

```
def unique(a):
    for i in a:
        set(a)
set([1,2,3])
```

print unique([1,1,2,3,2])

Define a function unique(a) that takes a list of numbers a and returns a new list where each element of a occurs only once. The new list should have its elements in the same order as they appear in a. Your function must use a set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's inconsiderate of other people's time to just dump your question like this. Please take some time to read [the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

[set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) is what you want :

```
>>> a=[1,1,2,2,3,3]
>>> set(a)
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: @Nick if a is a string passed a argument, just do set(list(a))

Comment: see thats what I thought theres so much to learn in python in a semester trying to figure out what do seems to mash into various lectures:P

Comment: still getting print unique([1,1,2,3,2]) to return none :(

Comment: sorry karsa i just did add my most recent